# Detect FFmpeg installation and Version

Tags: php, ffmpeg, command, version

I'm writing a PHP script that converts uploaded video files to FLV on the fly, but I only want it to run that part of the script if the user has FFmpeg installed on the server.

Would there be a way to detect this ahead of time? Could I perhaps run an FFmpeg command and test whether it comes back "command not found?"

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
$ffmpeg = trim(shell_exec('which ffmpeg')); // or better yet:
$ffmpeg = trim(shell_exec('type -P ffmpeg'));
```

If it comes back empty ffmpeg is not available, otherwise it will hold the absolute path to the executable, which you may use in the actual ffmpeg call:

```
if (empty($ffmpeg))
{
    die('ffmpeg not available');
}

shell_exec($ffmpeg . ' -i ...');
```

Answer (score 6):

The third parameter to the `exec()` function is the return value of the executed program. Use it like this:

```
exec($cmd, $output, $returnvalue);
if ($returnvalue == 127) {
    # not available
}
else {
    #available
}
```

This works on my Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 3):

You answered your own question, you can run the command and if it comes back negative you know it is not installed, or you can check the default paths the user has set for possible ffmpeg binaries.

Comment: Thanks. Could you demonstrate how I could evaluate the return of an exec() command in PHP? Is PHP smart enough to return false if the command doesn't work? That would surprise me.

Comment: Sample: if (strpos(`ffmpeg --help`, 'ffmpeg') > -1) echo 'Installed!';

Comment: @Cd-MaN: Unless that turns to output a message similar to **The package ffmpeg is not installed, you can install it by running...**. Also, `strpos` doesn't work as the Javascript equivalent, you have to test it against `!== false`.

Answer (score 1):

hi i search for this issue and i can get version of ffmpeg by this code:
echo(shell_exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -version'));

Answer (score -1):

You could give this a try:

```
function commandExists($command) {
    $command = escapeshellarg($command);
    $exists = exec("man ".$command,$out);
    return sizeof($out);
}

if (commandExists("ffmpeg")>0) {
   // FFMPeg Exists on server
} else {
   // No FFMPeg
}
```

Reusable for other functions as well - not certain of security concerns.

Comment: This is a very bad way to check for a command. Installed man pages don't mean that the program is installed - and vice-versa. It's enough to check for the executable itself.

Comment: Fair enough, it was the first idea that popped to mind and worked on the server that I tested it on, thought I would see if it worked for the OP as well.